# asp net core how to publish data from http get request to Rabbit MQ using mass transit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have just started to use RabbitMQ and I don't really get some things. What I need to do for now is take the data I received from a http get request using a named http client and then publish it to a queue in rabbit mq using mass transit. All the tutorials I have tried only show to post data to a certain queue, using postman, so I don't really know which is the right approach. Could someone please give me a little insight?

Comment: If you [start at the beginning](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLx8uyNNs1ri2MBx6BjPum5j9_MMdIfM9C), you can see an API posting data to RabbitMQ within the first two episodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will!

Comment: is there a way to have the data published without passing arguments to the http post method?

Comment: I don't understand, but there are various ways to pass data to Http action methods - however they all end up as arguments to the action method in the controller. That is unrelated to MassTransit, that's how ASP.NET Core works.